# PostgreSQL timestamp field

Tags: postgresql, time

I received an API Response from newsml.org for a timestamp as:

`2019-10-31T23:49:17Z`

I need to store this value in a Database, what would be the correct Date/Time field in Postgres?

Comment: I would recommend a field of type ```timestamp with time zone``` (shorter alias is ```timestamptz```). Then just insert ```'2019-10-31T23:49:17Z'::timestamptz``` to this field.

Comment: For further information you might have a look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html and perhaps also of interest is https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid `postgresql` timestamp, so should be able to store this without any issues.
But need to make sure to cast this to `timestamp` first.

```
cast('2019-10-31T23:49:17Z' as TIMESTAMP)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is completely missing ```timestamp with time zone```.

Comment: @Islingre, OP didn't mention timezone

Comment: The ```Z``` at the end of the string is a timezone specifier. It stands for Zulu-time (UTC).

Comment: Do ```SELECT '2019-10-31T23:49:17Z'::timestamptz;``` and compare the result (which should be different if your ```TimeZone``` is not UTC)

Comment: Besides this: I am curios about your result picture.. If I do the cast as you said, I get ```2019-10-31 23:49:17```, no ```Z``` anymore. Where does this come from? And it also should not show up anywhere in an timestamp-only (meaning without time zone) field

Comment: @Islingre, try this https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=Jt0UhRp1Ep

Comment: Saw this... Feels strange anyways.. db-fiddle seems to alyways show the ```Z``` after a timestamp (no matter if with or without time zone).. Doing this statement directly on console with ```psql```, you will not get the ```Z``` (I could try to speculate this is a result of the JS happening at the site, but I got no evidence)

Comment: i think postgresql 7.3 up, will add it automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201698/discussion-between-islingre-and-).

Answer (score -1):

Valid input for the time stamp types consists of the concatenation of a date and a time, followed by an optional time zone, thus:

1999-01-08 04:05:06 
and:

1999-01-08 04:05:06 -8:00

are both valid values.

The SQL standard differentiates timestamp without time zone and timestamp with time zone literals by the presence of a "+" or "-" symbol and time zone offset after the time. Hence, according to the standard,

```
TIMESTAMP '2004-10-19 10:23:54'
```

is a timestamp without time zone, while the below is:

```
TIMESTAMP '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'
```

For full documentation, refer to postgreSQL documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html